# change location of polar bar on map-python

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have map with locations in that area. I want to add 1/6 circle starting from each point in a specific direction so I decided to use polar plot with only one bar.
My locations is of the type(lat,lon) but the code accept location with only one parameter

I saw the same code all over the internet but still after reading the documantation its not working.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#I removed this line
plt.axes([0,0,1,1])

N = 20
theta = np.arange(0.0, 2*np.pi, 2*np.pi/N)
radii = 10*np.random.rand(N)
width = np.pi/4*np.random.rand(N)
bars = plt.bar(theta, radii, width=width, bottom=0.0)

for r,bar in zip(radii, bars):
    bar.set_facecolor( cm.jet(r/10.))
    bar.set_alpha(0.5)

plt.show()
```

right now, when runing it, I don't see a thing eventhough ax belong to my graph

Comment: The result of your code is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzvfr.png). It's not a polar plot, because you haven't set the projection to polar (`plt.axes([0,0,1,1], projection="polar")`)

Comment: I removed the plt.axex line, but still, even when I add it, the center of the circle is in the middle of the map and not at a specific location. changing the "buttom" field doesn't change a thing

Comment: What map are you talking about? You need `projection="polar"` to get a polar plot, so when you remove that, it cannot give a polar plot.

Comment: ok, now I understand you, I'm talking about map of a country, so I want that the polar backgraound will be invisible, and the center of each plot will be in different places, is it possible?

Comment: You would need several polar axes, and position each at the location you want to have it at.

Comment: several lines like this: plt.axes([0, 0, 1, 1], projection="polar") ?